# Can we get a float answer by dividing two ints?

Tags: c, floating-point

```
int8_t a;
int8_t b;
int8_t result;
result = (a*coeff) + b*(1-coeff);
```

Now this coeff has to be 0.5, but I cant store a float because of memory restrictions. Is there any way above operation can be performed?

Thanks

Comment: You could get something similar with `(a+b)/2`, is this what you want? For other coefficients you could look for rational values that approximate it.

Comment: @Guido: 0.5 is juust an arbitrary number. It can be 0.6, 0.7

Comment: Let's say it's 0.7. We can get that by doing (a*7 + b*(10-7))/10. Generalzing, if we approximate `coeff` by `c1 / c2`, you can calculate `(a*c1 + b*(c2-c1))/c2`. If coeff is not known at compile time this gets tricky.

Comment: The coeff is known. I am just wondering if that (what you suggested) would be a good approach, or fixed-point math

Comment: @UnderDog: That **is** fixed-point maths ;)

Comment: Oh. M sorry for being ignorant. I thought bit shifting (what zan suggested) was fixed-point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as if [fixed-point math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) is the answer you need here. In fixed-point, you decide how much of your integer size you want to give up. Then you shift the radix point (the decimal point in base-10) that many places over (in binary, usually).

So if you want to have a resolution of 0.25 you'd shift 2 bits. In a 16-bit integer that would reduce your range from 32678 to just 8192.

Comment: Note also that the range reduction can be mitigated by performing the maths in a larger data type (so in the OP's case, switching to `int16_t` for intermediate values).

Comment: I am trying to understand your logic here .. So if I shift to int16_t, and 0.6 is coeff, how do we figure out the shifting. I am sorry I didnt understand this part

Comment: @UnderDog: For example, you could multiply by `154` (that's round(2^8 * 0.6)) and then right-shift the result by 8.

Answer (score 0):

If `coeff` is already a floating point type, then everything is fine. The expressions involving it will be converted to a floating point type, and the final result will be converted back to an `int`.

Comment: No. coeff is not floating point, and I cannot store a floating point.

Comment: It seems you might want to inform us a bit more about your specific platform then. Although Fixed-point math would be a likely candidate.

Comment: Fixed-point math should work (at least seems like it). I am trying to understand how to implement it. (@Zan's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You might find a [rational number library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/rational/rational.html) to be a useful thing. This stores numbers as ratios of integers, like 1/4 or 255/256.